# How to fix StrikeFont»doesNotUnderstand: #glyphRendererOn: when rendering text in Roassal 2 on Pharo 3

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, roassal, athens

When you load Roassal 2 on Pharo 3 and try anything that involves text rendering, you get the following error message:

```
StrikeFont»doesNotUnderstand: #glyphRendererOn:
```

I could find some advice in the forums, that you have to

- enable True Type fonts (Settings Browser → Appearance → Use Free Type) and
- update the font list by executing `FreeTypeFontProvider current updateFromSystem.`

But the error remained the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roassal 2 seems to use the Default Standard Font for it’s text rendering.

So apart from enabling and updating True Type fonts, you also have to make sure to **select a True Type font as your Default Standard Font**, for example via the Settings Browser:

Settings Browser → Appearance → Standard Fonts → Default